# What is the recommended way to optimize MySQL connections in App Engine for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm building a pretty conventional PHP/MySQL back end to a mobile app, and I've been bitten hard for not closing MySQL connections properly in the past...

If I'm using mysqli_connect() to connect my App Engine-based PHP to the Google Cloud SQL, how do I make sure that I keep the number of simultaneous connections to my Cloud SQL instance at a minimum if user sessions could be quite long?

I've read that PHP 5.3+ supports persistent connections with mysqli_connect as long as you prepend the hostname with "p:" but Cloud SQL doesn't take *any* hostname at all when connecting from App Engine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend `p:` to anything that is the first parameter in your `mysql_connect`.

BUT you'll have to check if the time to open/close the connexion matters in comparison with the "data" query time, as stated in [google gloud SQL FAQ](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/faq#connections):

> How to best manage your database connections depends on your use case. For example, if the time to create a new database connection is greater than checking and reusing an existing connection, then we recommend you use connection pooling. Conversely, if the time to create a new connection is about the same as testing if an existing connection is alive and reusing it, then we recommend that you create a new connection to service each HTTP request, and reuse it for the duration of the request. In particular, the latter case may apply when you connect from Google App Engine to Google Cloud SQL.

To keep the number of SQL connexion low, you'll have to make extensive use of cache (with memcached for instance) and avoid doing connexion when you don't have to (ie do not create a connexion in the header of your page if you do not need it).

Comment: Awesome! The Cloud SQL FAQ has a wealth of stuff I wasn't finding because I was looking for PHP-specific items...thanks!